# Enhance python lsp-mode with elpy functions and keybindings

Tags: python, elpy, config

I've been using Elpy for a long time and have grown used to many of the default keybindings. I recently decided to give lsp-mode a go to see how it compares. I set it up following [this blog](https://vxlabs.com/2018/06/08/python-language-server-with-emacs-and-lsp-mode/) and made my own tweaks. There's things I really like about it, like the lsp-ui-peek functions. It also seems to work a bit better with Jedi sometimes. However, I also miss a lot of the navigation and code formatting functionality that Elpy supplies. For example, I really like the following functions:

elpy-nav-*, elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer

Does anyone have any configuration suggestions to integrate some of this without having to copy all the desired Elpy functionality into my init file or having to enable all of Elpy?

Comment: Did you ever find a good approach for the two to coexist?

Comment: @dpritch Unfortunately no... I ended up giving up with `lsp-mode` for now and going back to `elpy`

Comment: I can see from the elpy documentation that you can [load the package from source](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#manually-from-sources) and then load individual elpy modules. Would this do the trick for you?